# Overriding jetty port setting when using Build.scala files

Tags: scala, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin

I am moving my build from *build.sbt* to *Build.scala* files and I am having trouble overriding the jetty port setting when using the *xsbt-web-plugin*. When using *build.sbt* I was able to set the property using:

```
port in container.Configuration := 8081
```

In my .scala files I have tried a few things but jetty is always starting on 8080 for example in my *BuildSettings* object:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import com.earldouglas.xsbtwebplugin.PluginKeys._
object BuildSettings {
  lazy val settings =  com.earldouglas.xsbtwebplugin.WebPlugin.webSettings ++ seq(
    ...
    port := 8081,
    ...
  ) 
}
```

I have also tried overriding it in the Project definition in *Build.scala*:

```
  lazy val root = Project("test",file("."))
    .settings(settings: _*)
    .settings(port := 8081)
```

But it always starts on 8080. In both of these cases running `show port` shows 8081.

Comment: Have you tried to use                                                 port in container.Configuration := 8081              like in your build.sbt?

Comment: I don't have a build.sbt in my project, I have moved to entirely .scala files rather than a mixed configuration.

Comment: I know. But you said it worked. So why not try to write it in your scala file in the same way (including in container.Configuration)?

Answer (score 5):

The issue is the web plugin is hiding its port setting inside a configuration.   It allows multiple containers with different port settings.  However, it *is not* pulling the port from the non-scoped key (as do a lot of plugins).

So you'll have to explicitly do:

port in  := 8081

On the sbt console if you do `inspect tree` on the server startup task, you'll probably see somewhere that it relies on `<config>:part` setting.

I think by default, you want:

```
port in container.Configuration := 8081
```

If you're in a .scala file you may also need to include the file which has `Container`, i.e.

```
import com.earldouglas.xsbtwebplugin.WebPlugin.container
```

I'd also recommend opening a feature request on the web plugin to automatically delegate the port setting to `Global` and specify the default there, for the default Web plugin.

You can mimic this yourself with these two settings:

```
port in container.Configuration := port in Global

port in Global := 8081
```

Hope that helps!